# Skip test method for specific type in generic test class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, nunit

I'm trying to unit test a part of a project; I'm using NUnit. The targeted unit processes objects of several types, all extending a base type. I've created a generic test class on which I set the desired test types:

```
[TestFixture(typeof(SomeType))]
[TestFixture(typeof(SomeOtherType))]
class MyTestClass<T> where T : SomeBaseType, new()
{

     [Test]
     public void DoThisTest()
     {
         var sut = CreateSut();
         var target = CreateTarget();

         Assert.IsTrue(sut.Process(target));
     }  

     [Test]
     public void DoThatTest()
     {
         var sut = CreateSut();
         var target = CreateInvalidTarget();

         Assert.IsFalse(sut.IsValid(target));
     }  

     //...
}
```

This creates a set of all the tests for each type set using `TestFixture`. For whatever reason, I have a test which only makes sense in the context of a specific type. This means that I need to either 1) use `Assert.Ignore()` on all other types or 2) create a different test class just for those "special" test cases.

Is there a way of opting out from a test from outside (attribute?) and specify that that particular test must not be "implemented" in certain contexts? I would like to "combine" 1) & 2) such that all the test cases are in the same file/class but some tests are only rendered/implemented/run for certain values set by `TestFixture`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but I think it's a pretty close work around.  You can specify nested classes within your main test fixture and decorate them with different `TestFixture` attributes to restrict what's run.  It's probably best explained with an example.  So, given these data types:

```
public interface ICompetitor {
    string GetFinalPosition();
}


public class Winner : ICompetitor{
    public string GetFinalPosition() {
        return "Won";
    }
}

public class Loser : ICompetitor {
    public string GetFinalPosition() {
        return "Lost";
    }
}
```

I can define these TestFixtures:

```
[TestFixture(typeof(Winner))]
[TestFixture(typeof(Loser))]
public class CompetitorTests<T> where T : ICompetitor, new()
{
    static private T CreateSut() {
        return new T();
    }

    [Test]
    public void EverybodyHasPosition() {
        Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(CreateSut().GetFinalPosition());
    }

    [TestFixture(typeof(Winner))]
    public class WinnerTests {
        [Test]
        public void TestWon() {
            Assert.AreEqual("Won", CompetitorTests<T>.CreateSut().GetFinalPosition());
        }
    }

    [TestFixture(typeof(Loser))]
    public class LoserTests {
        [Test]
        public void TestLost() {
            Assert.AreEqual("Lost", CompetitorTests<T>.CreateSut().GetFinalPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

The `EverybodyHasPosition` test is run twice (once for the `Winner` and once for the `Loser` classes).  Whereas the `TestWon` is only run for the `Winner` class and the `TestLost` is only run for the `Loser` class.  It's not ideal, because you can only access static members of the outer class, and each fixture is responsible for it's own setup/teardown.

You can work around this though, by using a base class.  So, the state sharing version might look more like this (notice that each `TestFixture` inherits from `CompetitorTestsState`):

```
public class CompetitorTestsState<T> where T : ICompetitor, new()  {
    protected T SUT { get; private set; }

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup() {
        SUT = CreateSut();
    }

    private T CreateSut() {
        return new T();
    }
}

[TestFixture(typeof(Winner))]
[TestFixture(typeof(Loser))]
public class CompetitorTests<T> : CompetitorTestsState<T> where T : ICompetitor, new() {
    [Test]
    public void EverybodyHasPosition() {
        Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(SUT.GetFinalPosition());
    }

    [TestFixture(typeof(Winner))]
    public class WinnerTests : CompetitorTestsState<T>{
        [Test]
        public void TestWon() {
            Assert.AreEqual("Won", SUT.GetFinalPosition());
        }
    }

    [TestFixture(typeof(Loser))]
    public class LoserTests : CompetitorTestsState<T>{
        [Test]
        public void TestLost() {
            Assert.AreEqual("Lost", SUT.GetFinalPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to your second version but I don't really like it. The first version seams more elegant. I will make the changes when I get the chance. Thank you!